# After chrome extension turn on popup of website stop working how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I developed a chrome extension that find aspection ratio of image on mouseover. When i turn extension on its stoped pop up from working. I find following warnings in console but no error.

```
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://bibbkmhpfhghkgfilffhegjbhgcchclg/vendor/js/popper.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://bibbkmhpfhghkgfilffhegjbhgcchclg/vendor/js/bootstrap.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME.
```

Here is my manifest

```
{
      "manifest_version": 2,

      "name": "Aspect Ratio",
      "description": "Find any Image aspect ratio",
      "version": "1.0",

      "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Image"
      },
      // "icons": {
      //   "16": "assets/images/logo/16.png",
      //   "48": "assets/images/logo/48.png",
      //   "128": "assets/images/logo/128.png"
      // },
      "permissions": ["storage"],
      "content_scripts": [
       {
         "matches": ["https://www.dianxiaomi.com/*"],
         "css":["vendor/css/bootstrap.min.css"],
         "js":["vendor/js/jquery.min.js","vendor/js/popper.min.js","vendor/js/bootstrap.min.js","assets/content.js"]
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: in console do you see any error ?

Comment: No just warnings

Comment: DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://cpcccoeohnldhlfomjmgknnoegkbkfgb/vendor/js/popper.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Comment: checkout extension source that all the assets js are loaded and shown in that source ?

Comment: yes if i remove .map all the js works

Comment: try giving js without folder and files to be at root level  

----------js: ["jquery.min.js"] -- -- all the files in this array to be at root level